# Ignore both uppercase and lowercase versions of the extensions listed in completion-ignored-extensions

Tags: files, completion

How can I get Emacs to ignore, say, both `.pdf` and  `.PDF` files without listing both `".pdf"` and  `".PDF"` in `completion-ignored-extensions`?

Comment: The question seems unclear. (1) Do you want to ignore only the file names `.pdf` and `.PDF` or any file name that ends in those? (2) Ignore where/when? Just during completion when reading a file name (e.g. `read-file-name`)?

Answer (score 1):

Quoth [`(emacs) Completion Options`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html), the paragraph just before `completion-ignored-extensions` is described:

```
   When completing file names, case differences are ignored if the
variable ‘read-file-name-completion-ignore-case’ is non-‘nil’.  The
default value is ‘nil’ on systems that have case-sensitive file-names,
such as GNU/Linux; it is non-‘nil’ on systems that have case-insensitive
file-names, such as Microsoft Windows.  When completing buffer names,
case differences are ignored if the variable
‘read-buffer-completion-ignore-case’ is non-‘nil’; the default is ‘nil’.
```

If `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` is `nil`, and `completion-ignored-extensions` includes only `".pdf"`, then `".PDF"` will not be ignored.

If you customise `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` to be non-`nil`, and `completion-ignored-extensions` includes only `".pdf"`, then both `".pdf"` and `".PDF"` will be ignored.

If you want general file name completion (e.g. on the non-extension part) to be case-sensitive, and only `completion-ignored-extensions` matching to be case-insensitive, then you need to include both `".pdf"` and `".PDF"` in `completion-ignored-extensions`.

Comment: I want completion to stay case sensitive but I'd like the convenience of excluding files from `ido`'s completion just by listing their lowercase extension. What I was looking for was something like running `upcase` on each extension using `dolist` (I didn't know about them back then). But in the end just having `".JPG" ".PDF" ".PNG"` in the list is enough to cover the great majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you want to include file names that *end in* `.pdf` and `.PDF`, *except* for the two file names that are *just those strings* (nothing before the dot).

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can do this by setting or binding option `icicle-file-no-match-regexp` to a regexp that excludes matching file-name candidates. You could use `"^[.]pdf$"` (or `"^[.][pP][dD][fF]$"`).